# How to handle CRUD operations for CREATE and DUPLICATE

Tags: rest, wcf, crud

I have an interface that takes Action objects across a CRUD api.  To create an Action in the first place, you must call my CreateAction() factory method.

To *duplicate* it, however, should I make the user call a duplicate method?  The client can trivially duplicate each field, but fields could be added later and the client wouldn't know about them.

Right now I just have the client call Create to get a second instance and then copy everything over but the name.  That works.  But it feels wrong because the object could evolve and the client would only be copying fields it knew about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it feels wrong because the object could evolve and the client would only be copying fields it knew about.

That's a good feeling to have, nurture it.

> The client can trivially duplicate each field, but fields could be added later and the client wouldn't know about them.

Think about how you would do it with a web page running in a browser.

The client would probably GET some resource, and then look around for an affordance that would allow the client to request a duplicate.  That would probably look like a link to a new resource, which would present to the client a form.  When the client submits the form, that message communicates to the server the request to create a duplicate.

As an integration protocol, the client's part looks like

- Get a representation of the original resource
- Look for the *link* that gives access to the duplication form, and follow it
- Look for the *form*, and submit it

Key point one: if you don't want the client to duplicate the resource, you simply remove the link from the representation.

Key point two: you can add editable content to the form, which will allow clients that understand the semantics to make their own changes.  The dumb clients that don't understand the semantics are going to ignore those fields, so you'll need to make sure that you provide default values that preserve backwards compatibility.